# GitKraken fails to launch on Debian Stretch

Tags: linux, debian

I installed .deb from official site and checked all dependencies, but it still fails to launch. How can i fix it? Here is log:

```
keddad@hardpc:~$ gitkraken

(gitkraken:4637): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:68:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-x is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(gitkraken:4637): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:69:35: The style property GtkButton:child-displacement-y is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version

(gitkraken:4637): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:73:46: The style property GtkScrolledWindow:scrollbars-within-bevel is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. It will be removed in a future version
Node started time: 1543211603684
libgnome-keyring.so.0: Ð½ÐµÐ²Ð¾Ð·Ð¼Ð¾Ð¶Ð½Ð¾ Ð¾ÑÐºÑÑÑÑ ÑÐ°Ð·Ð´ÐµÐ»ÑÐµÐ¼ÑÐ¹ Ð¾Ð±ÑÐµÐºÑÐ½ÑÐ¹ ÑÐ°Ð¹Ð»: ÐÐµÑ ÑÐ°ÐºÐ¾Ð³Ð¾ ÑÐ°Ð¹Ð»Ð° Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ ÐºÐ°ÑÐ°Ð»Ð¾Ð³Ð°
Error: libgnome-keyring.so.0: Ð½ÐµÐ²Ð¾Ð·Ð¼Ð¾Ð¶Ð½Ð¾ Ð¾ÑÐºÑÑÑÑ ÑÐ°Ð·Ð´ÐµÐ»ÑÐµÐ¼ÑÐ¹ Ð¾Ð±ÑÐµÐºÑÐ½ÑÐ¹ ÑÐ°Ð¹Ð»: ÐÐµÑ ÑÐ°ÐºÐ¾Ð³Ð¾ ÑÐ°Ð¹Ð»Ð° Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ ÐºÐ°ÑÐ°Ð»Ð¾Ð³Ð°
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:671:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:180:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/node_modules/keytar/lib/keytar.js:4:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/node_modules/keytar/lib/keytar.js:58:4)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like libraries were missing, even though apt didn't say it. Simply

```
sudo apt install libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring-dev
```